# Obtaining Android Contacts Sorting Preference

Tags: android, android-intent

Inside "Contacts" -> "Settings" in android, we have "Sort list by" and "view contact name as" options. Is there any way of obtaining these preferences inside another app? Meaning my app has my own version of a contact list. I need these in order to sort it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    int sort_order = 
Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),ContactsContract.Preferences.SORT_ORDER);
    inr display_order =
Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),ContactsContract.Preferences.DISPLAY_ORDER);
```

Comment: what are the integers returned and what do the integers mean, if you can help some more ? :D

Comment: http://www.androidjavadoc.com/2.3/android/provider/ContactsContract.Preferences.html

Comment: @RocketRandom Can u provide answer for api level 10 onwards?