# Sorting the name list in my app - SettingNotFoundException

Tags: android

I'm writing an application which sorts the names of employees based on the user's selection in his/her Contacts settings.

I have implemented the following code in my application for fetching the sort order from device's Contacts:

```
int sortOrder = 0;

try{
  sortOrder = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), "android.contacts.DISPLAY_ORDER");
} catch (android.provider.Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
  Log.e("Setting Not Found", e.getMessage());
}
```

My application is working fine with below 5.0 version devices, but i have a problem with Nexus5 (6.0). It always throws:

> android.provider.Settings$SettingNotFoundException: android.contacts.DISPLAY_ORDER

I tried the example from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569896/get-sorting-order-preference-selected-user-in-contactssettings-in-android-devic), but no luck.

Comment: Did this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357115/obtaining-android-contacts-sorting-preference

Comment: ContactsContract.Preferences.SORT_ORDER it was giving error that cannot resolve symbol 'Preferences'

Comment: Adding this on the top of the java file import android.provider.ContactsContract.Preferences; solve the problem?

Comment: No its not importing the Preferences package. Showing error there as well. Should we have any specefic JDK or android SDK for adding ContactsContract.Preferences?

Comment: Any help on this please?

Comment: Could any one please help me on this?

Comment: Is there any permissions required in menifest for fetching data ?

Comment: i have given all the permissions in manifest

Comment: Anyone please help me on this

Comment: Any one help me please?